# How to use nested json object with ngFor

Tags: json, angular, loops, ngfor

I have a problem iterating through a json object to display messages.
The scenario is that I have messages sent `from_id` to `to_id` and the `jsonData` as follow:

```
jsonData={
    "chat":
    {
        "79":
        {
            "from":"Testing Page - joe",
            "from_id":79,
            "to":"userTestName",
            "to_id":1548,
            "unread":2,
            "messages":
            [
                {"id":154,"page_id":79,"user_id":1548,"text":"this is the first message to be sent by joe","seen":0,"isgroup":0,"group_id":null,"created_at":"2019-04-10 13:54:10","updated_at":"2019-04-10 13:54:10"},
                {"id":155,"page_id":79,"user_id":1548,"text":"this is the second message sent to joe","seen":0,"isgroup":0,"group_id":null,"created_at":"2019-04-11 12:37:39","updated_at":"2019-04-11 12:37:39"}
            ]
        },
        "44":
        {
            "from":"Rock Music Band",
            "from_id":44,
            "to":"userTestName",
            "to_id":1548,
            "unread":1,
            "messages":
            [
                {"id":156,"page_id":44,"user_id":1548,"text":"Hello this message from rock","seen":0,"isgroup":0,"group_id":null,"created_at":"2019-04-11 13:18:44","updated_at":"2019-04-11 13:18:44"}
            ]
        }
    },
    "unread":3
}
```

I am facing a problem to display these messages in a `<ul>` using angular `*ngFor`:

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let messageData of jsonData.chat;>
      <div class="message-info">
        <h4>{{messageData.from}}</h4>
        <h4>{{messageData.messages[0].text}}</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I'm getting the error of not supported object.

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

What should my jsonData look like in order to display messages? I want each id `79` - `44' to be a separate object.

Comment: You have to convert the object into an array. NgFor only works on arrays, and not objects

Comment: `jsonData.chat` is not an array, this is the only reason you are getting an Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonData` is an object and not an array, therefore the error. You might want to use the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe):

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of jsonData.chat | keyvalue>
    <div class="message-info">
      <h4>{{jsonData.chat[data.key].from}}</h4> <!-- Or even better: data.value.from -->
      <h4>{{jsonData.chat[data.key].messages[0].text}}</h4> <!-- Or even better: data.value.messages[0].text -->
      <!-- Want to loop through your messages? -->
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let message of data.value.messages">{{message.text}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Though it might be worth it to transform your data into an array.

Comment: thank you, but this requires to update my angular dependencies in order to use keyValue, can you please show how to convert my json data to array without changing any keys in the given json data ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to format your json as an Array in order for ngFor to work,
I think this is what you are looking for : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7ezpn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
  "chat":
  [
      {"title" :"79",
      "content":
      {
          "from":"Testing Page - joe",
          "from_id":79,
          "to":"userTestName",
          "to_id":1548,
          "unread":2,
          "messages":
          [
              {"id":154,"page_id":79,"user_id":1548,"text":"this is the first message to be sent by joe","seen":0,"isgroup":0,"group_id":null,"created_at":"2019-04-10 13:54:10","updated_at":"2019-04-10 13:54:10"},
              {"id":155,"page_id":79,"user_id":1548,"text":"this is the second message sent to joe","seen":0,"isgroup":0,"group_id":null,"created_at":"2019-04-11 12:37:39","updated_at":"2019-04-11 12:37:39"}
          ]
      }},
      {
       "title" :"44",
       "content":
      {
          "from":"Rock Music Band",
          "from_id":44,
          "to":"userTestName",
          "to_id":1548,
          "unread":1,
          "messages":
          [
              {"id":156,"page_id":44,"user_id":1548,"text":"Hello this message from rock","seen":0,"isgroup":0,"group_id":null,"created_at":"2019-04-11 13:18:44","updated_at":"2019-04-11 13:18:44"}
          ]
      }}
  ],
  "unread":3
}
```